# Detect IP Connection and disconnection

Tags: javascript

I'm begginer in node.js. So I would like to know the best way to detect if a specific local IP (192.168.100.70) has connected or disconnected to my server. Thanks!

Comment: What kind of server is this? Are you creating an HTTP server or just a TCP one? (The answer is different depending on the API)

Answer (score 0):

Nodejs have the ability to track the connected and disconnected user IP Address with socket.io node package. Socket.io enables real-time directions which is event based communication. Its works on all the platform, browser or device on reliability and speed.